# Textmate2: change autocomplete key

Tags: keyboard, key-bindings, textmate2

I´m trying to change the keybinding in textmate2 - I want to change autocompletion from "ESC" to "cmd + space" but I don´t know how.

In Textmate (1) you could do that by editing the shortcuts in the osx preferneces/keyboard settings - but the Menu title from textmate (Next Completion) isn´t the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the solution:

osX Preferneces / Keyboard Settings / Shortcuts

App Shortcuts - add a new one for TextMate2 - The Menu titel is "completion"